# JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 220200961 (char 220200960)

Tags: python, json, parsing, data-science

I am saving the audio features in a JSON file, and then I am trying to fetch the JSON file to read the features. However, when I am doing it on my own PC, it works like a charm. But when I am trying the same code on Google Colab, it gives me the error. My JSON file is very big, hence, I am sharing the dataframe that I converted to JSON -

Screenshot from my PC -

[image: Screenshot from my PC]

Screenshot from Google Colab -

[image: Screenshot from Google Colab]

Here's the code -

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('audio_feature1.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

featuresdf_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data))
featuresdf_new.tail()
```

Here's a sample of the JSON file -

```
[
  {"feature":[[-442.6738586426,-251.5938262939,-185.341003418]],
   "class_label":"Hip-Hop"},
  {"feature":[[-440.8941040039,-278.483795166,-201.6567993164]],
   "class_label":"Hip-Hop"},
  {"feature":[[-167.9207611084,-65.8354110718,-34.5040512085]],
   "class_label":"Pop"}
]
```

With reference to the previous articles, I understand if there have been a problem with my JSON, even my PC would not have been able to read the file, clearly, there is no problem with the JSON file that has been created.

Comment: don't post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. The JSON file eventually threw errors for maximum iteration for very big data. However, I used the Pickle file format, which was way faster than the loading and dumping in JSON.